# Where can I find the coherence funtion in r?

Tags: text-mining, text2vec

Excuse me for being basic, but I want to use the 'coherence' function I found on this [link](https://rdrr.io/github/dselivanov/text2vec/man/coherence.html) to evaluate my latent dirichlet allocation topics and it isn't working with text2vec and I can't tell which library it is in, if it isn't that one.

```
coherence(x, tcm, metrics = c("mean_logratio", "mean_pmi", "mean_npmi",
  "mean_difference", "mean_npmi_cosim", "mean_npmi_cosim2"), smooth = 1e-12,
  n_doc_tcm = -1)
```

Comment: It is there, but in the development version on github.You can install in with `remotes::install_github("dselivanov/text2vec@0.6")`

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov Big fan. Thank you so much, hopefully I'll be able to use this state of the art library soon enough!

Comment: As a quick workaround, @DmitriySelivanov could I access each topic in order to apply another lda to each one of them? Like having two levels in the topic model, i.e. topic one is created by 3 topics

Comment: each document is a mixture of topics. So you can filter documents where some topic "occupy" more than certain threshold and then fit anther LDA on them.